# Can I replace the cfgridkey with my own custom variable name? Or else build my own href?

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

I have a simple cfgrid that's displaying my ids. I want the id to be a link to a new page, passing a url parameter of "myID" with the id value.

I've tried this code:

```
<cfgrid name="myGrid" query="myQuery" format="html">
   <cfgridcolumn name="myID" href="mynewpage.cfm" />
</cfgrid>
```

But this takes me to the url "mynewpage.cfm?**hrefkey**=111". What I really want is "mynewpage.cfm?**myID**=111". Is there any way to specify what the name of the url parameter should be?

I've also tried:

```
<cfgrid name="myGrid" query="myQuery" format="html">
   <cfgridcolumn name="myID" href="mynewpage.cfm?myID=#myID#" />
</cfgrid>
```

But then I get the error "`myID is not defined`". Is there any way to reference query field values from within a cfgridcolumn tag?

**UPDATE:**

Another thing I've tried - building the string in the sql query so that I return a column called `myURL` with a value of "mynewpage.cfm?myID=111", and then using that column for the href attribute:

```
<cfgrid name="myGrid" query="myQuery" format="html">
   <cfgridcolumn name="myID" href="#myURL#" />
</cfgrid>
```

According to the [coldfusion documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_g-h_04.html) you should be able to do this:

> href - URL *or query column name* that contains a URL to hyperlink each grid
>   column with.

(italics mine)

But I get the error "`myURL is not defined`". How do I set the href to a column rather than a literal url value?

Comment: I did a brief search and only found threads [like this](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/510290) or [this one](http://forums.forta.com/messages.cfm?threadid=C72175F0-0974-85CE-B1052899FF1E9AAD) which seem to indicate it is not possible. (Maybe by tapping into the extjs stuff?)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the `<cftree>`/`<cftreeitem>` problem using href. There does not seem to be a built-in solution for this. Either you deal with the provided keys and rename the whole address using outbound URL rewrite (IIS has native support, Apache can do this with [UrlRewriteFilter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html#outbound-rule)), or you might just switch to a different Javascript based grid.

Comment: Or you can set the href="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#", look for URL.CFGRIDKEY, and then do a cfheader to bounce the user to myURL, setting the myID part of the query string to #URL.CFGRIDKEY#

Answer (score 0):

One solution is in this page:

http://www.houseoffusion.com/cfdocs1/Developing_Web_Applications_with_ColdFusion/14_Building_Dynamic_Forms/dwa14_09.htm

Define a new column using

```
<cfset queryAddColumn(SPEREQ_QRY_UNFULFILLED, "CUST_LINK", ArrayNew(1)) />

<cfloop query="SPEREQ_QRY_UNFULFILLED">
  <cfset querySetCell(SPEREQ_QRY_UNFULFILLED, "CUST_LINK","index.cfm?action=contact_info&cust_id=#SPEREQ_QRY_UNFULFILLED.CUST_CNTCT_LMS_ID#", SPEREQ_QRY_UNFULFILLED.currentRow) />
</cfloop>
```

use this new column cust_link in the display

```
<cfgridcolumn name = "CUST_CNTCT_LMS_ID" header="CustID"  
     href="CUST_LINK" target="_blank" width="20">
<CFGRIDCOLUMN NAME="CUST_LINK" DISPLAY="No">
```

Comment: Why on earth are you pointing to CF4/4.5 documentation? It is over a decade old, and is probably referring to applets (yipes ;-) not `format=html`...